# I deploy my next app to vercel and the callback URL always equals to localhost

Tags: javascript, next.js, vercel, next-auth, next.js13

I deploy my **next 13** app to **vercel** and the `callback URL` always equals to **localhost**.

this is my **login** url :

```
https://best-planning.vercel.app/login?callbackUrl=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost/
```

and in the **cookies** the value of `next-auth.callback-url` is always  =
**http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost/**

- I change the **NEXTAUTH_URL** in production to point to my app `https://best-planning.vercel.app/`

Comment: Tip: if you are using vscode: search "localhost" in your files, replace that with  https://best-planning.vercel.app/. Also check environment variables

Comment: Check AUTH0_BASE_URL in your env varibles

Comment: I did all of that